# Different proxy per browser window

Tags: .net, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver, fiddler

I want to run several IE instances (via Selenium).

My plan is to have multiple FiddlerCore instances fired up and torn down for each test so I can see exactly what HTTP traffic there is per test.  Each instance created via the WebDriver would have it's proxy set to the instance of FiddlerCore created for that test.

1. Is this possible?
2. How would I go about it?

If it's impossible, any suggestions on an alternative strategy?

e.g. Would it be possible to get the PID of the browser windows and filter each instance of FiddlerCore to listen only to that process?

I'm using .NET Selenium and the standard `IEWebDriver.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this isn't usually easy but it's often possible.

The "best" way to do this would be to have a single FiddlerCore instance that determines where traffic is coming from based on the process ID, sorting each process' traffic into its own list or whatever.

The challenge you run into is that different IE "instances" can end up merging into a single process; have you tried running a full Fiddler instance while running your test to see if the PIDs are split as you hope?

Comment: I can disable frame merging, assuming Selenium lets me pass arguments to the processes it creates, but even if I got past that hurdle there's no way to get the PIDs of the processes that the WebDriver creates.  I'm now going down the root of a bespoke solution.  If it works I'll post it up here.

Comment: The other option I considered was having FiddlerCore running all the time, but I don't know if it'll listen to multiple ports and if it does, whether I can filter on what traffic it got from what port.